# Joomla Menu Structuring

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, url

I'm looking to alter the menu structure of my site, to add better segmentation and ultimately create a portion of the site for google news. As it exists right now, my menu structure looks something like:

www.example.com/article

and I'm looking to translate it to:

www.example.com/news/articles

This will help me to delimit the sections of the site that I would like to submit as news articles. How would I go about doing this? Hopefully I'm being clear, let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using sh404sef? If you are, the way you would do this would be different.

Comment: @moomoochoo No, we aren't using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve the URL structure you mention is to create a Category called "News" and create your news articles in this category. This will give you a structure like:

```
www.example.com/news/news1  
www.example.com/news/news2  
www.example.com/news/news3
```

Creating a sub-category under news could further refine this if needed:

```
www.example.com/news/politics/news4
```

By the way, take care in Joomla to create menu links to the categories themselves to ensure correct URL and breadcrumb structure is generated.

Comment: Awesome, my only concern would be the amount of control you have over the following section:

Www.example.com/news/news1 

The format that I'm hoping for here is: 

www.example.com/news/articleName

Comment: If you want to get rid of the ids you have to create menu items for each article or use an extension like sh404

Comment: The ArticleName in the URL you provide is taken from the "Item alias URL" field in the Joomla article editor. You have complete control over how this appears. As always with Joomla - if something doesn't show as it should - check your menu links to the respective article/category. The menu settings for each article can override many other settings (and adds to the learning curve in Joomla).